# Payload is empty in Titanium app but notifications are receiving successfully in other app

Tags: push-notification, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

- There is an app which has been just completed on PhoneGap (PG) by a company.
- That company's backend team has integrated Push notifications in it and it is working fine in PG.
- Now, I have been developing this app in Titanium (only dealing with front-end) and I have successfully registered the app for Push using CloudPush Android module (using same GCM Server Key and Sender ID as in PG app) and I can easily receive Push messages through Appcelerator Dashboard (or Arrow DB), but upon receiving that company's push message, my app is getting crashed after throwing error that "Payload is empty".
- At the same time, their PG app is easily receiving Push messages.
- Today morning, I just talked to their backend team and they told me that they have not formatted the payload according to Titanium.

What should I do to make Titanium app work and whether they are wrong in their words or is there really something like formatting data according to Titanium???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re not using Arrow to send push notifications to the app, then you probably can better use one of the general GCM modules out there to receive the push message as indeed our module might expect a certain format (although I’m not 100% sure):

http://gitt.io/search?q=gcm

Comment: Thanks Fokke, and pardon me to reply so late because I was confirming this issue with our backend team.
Now its clear that our cloudpush module always need a certain format.
Refer this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx46j4nux858a75/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-31%20at%207.37.15%20PM.png?dl=0